# want to overlap 2 divs so even when window is scaled, they don't move

Tags: html, css

I want to overlap two divs. One div is floated to the right and this is the css code for the other div. I want the div mentioned in the picture to overlap the first div.

```
#name {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 340px;
    height: 85px;
    background: #F0EDE5;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Currently, this div is floated to the left and I have tried float: right, display: absolute, z-index: 2, but nothing is working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That should be pretty easy. The following code shows the basic concept of overlapping DIVs. To solve your problem please show code including the parent.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box1, .box2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.box2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**Result**

[image: Result]